# What type of soil should I use for a galvanized steel planter for growing veggies?

Tags: vegetables, soil, potting-soil

I am not sure whether I should use potting soil or raised bed soil. This would have a bottom so the roots would not be going down to the actual soil (going to be putting it on concrete anyways).

Comment: composted wood chips make good soil if you have time to let them compost

Comment: Unfortunately I am not patient enough for that

Comment: A moist organic soil good for growing plants should corrode through galvanized sheet steel in a few years,depending on thickness.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=952) from the Royal Horticultural Society provides the formulations of a range of compost specifications used in the United Kingdom; from this source:

> [John Innes No 2] contains double the amount of nutrient in John Innes No 1 to suit established plants. It is suitable for most houseplants and vegetable plants in containers.

John Innes No 2 is formulated as:

- 7 parts sterilised loam (good quality topsoil - raised bed soil is probably approximately this)
- 3 parts peat or peat substitute
- 2 parts sand

Plus the addition of a variety of concentrated fertilisers and minerals described as "John Innes Base" which include:

- Hoof and horn meal (bonemeal or fish, blood and bone is **not** equivalent; the NPK ratios are different)
- Superphosphate
- Sulphate of potash

You may not find products labelled as such in your market, but if you look for potting compost with a similar formulation, you shouldn't go far wrong. You could also make your own to the above ratio with topsoil, well-rotted organic matter, sand, and a balanced slow-release fertiliser applied as per the pack directions.